# Using Thunderbird 78.9.1, what must I do to display "Important" message in red backcolor?

Tags: thunderbird, colors, label, background

In `Thunderbird` 78.9.1, I search to display some tagged messages with some specific backcolors.

Using `Options` in Thunderbird application, it is only possible to set forecolors !

I have found some pages on Internet indicating that it is possible using a `userchrome.css` file.

First of all, I set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true`

I have created multiple `chrome` folder in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Thunderbird\Profiles\nogjg7m8.default\chrome
```

and also in Roaming profile folder

```
C:\Users\berna\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird
```

But backcolor are always `white` !!!

What do I make wrong ?

My `userchrome.css` file contains following lines

```
/*Important tag*/ 
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(T_24label1)
{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF !important;
      background-color: #b71c1c !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1)
{
      color: #00FF00  !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(T_24label1, selected)
{
      background-color:  #FF0033   !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1, selected)
{
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

What is correct location for `userchrome.css` file on `Windows 10` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've misnamed your CSS file. The correct name is `userChrome.css` (note the capital letter `C`).

Incidentally, I dropped your CSS into my `userChrome.css` file (on Linux) in place of my own "Important tag" customization and it worked fine... assuming your intent was lime green text on a red background.

Comment: I work on Windows and on Windows the problem with file is never linked to filename and lower or upper cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem in founding the correct Folder for `UserChrome.css` file.

The folder is defined in `Account Paramaters`

[image]

The folder that is the sibling folder to `Mail` folder defined in `Local Folder` (see red arrow) is the directory in which `Chrome` folder must be defined

On my PC, `Local Folder` is equal to

```
D:\Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\nogjg7m8.default\Mail\pop.gmail.com
```

Chrome folder must be equal to

```
D:\Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\nogjg7m8.default\Chrome
```

And `UserChrome.css` file must be defined in this folder !

Here my current UserChrome.css file

```
/*Important tag*/ 
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(T_24label1)
{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF !important;
      background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1)
{
      color: #FFFF00  !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(T_24label1, selected)
{
      background-color:  #FFFFFF   !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1, selected)
{
      color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

`Important` messages are in Yellow on Red background.